# Sumar datos de una columna de un modelo para otro modelo RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tengo 2 modelos "***atriremis*** y ***remisiones***" atriremis esta creado con coccon que pertenece a remisiones, remisiones puede tener muchos atriremis, en atriremis tengo datos matematicos los cuales son multiplicados que son : "***cantidad*** y ***valor_unitario***" para formar un ***valor_total*** de un atriremi, como remisiones tiene muchos atriremis, al crear una remision tendria muchos atriremis los cuales cada una cuenta con un ***valor_total***. Remisiones tiene un ***valor_bruto*** que seria la suma de todos los valores totales de cada atriremi de la misma remision, no tengo la mas remota idea como hacer esto, el pasar estos datos entre modelos o como hacer la definicion.

Model de atriremis

```
class Atriremi < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :remision

  def valor_total
   cantidad * valor_unitario
 end

end
```

Show de remisiones

```
<% @remision.atriremis.each do |atriremi|%>
<p><strong>Valor tol :</strong><%=atriremi.valor_total%></p>
<%end%>
```

Eso es lo que tengo con respecto a ***valor_total*** pero con respecto a ***valor_bruto*** adsolutamente nada ya que no se que hacer ningun proceso, hasta ahora solo lo tengo como una entrada en el formulario de remisiones

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <h5><%= f.input :valor_bruto %></h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero necesitas obtener todos los `Atriremi` relacionados, lo cual logras mediante la relación `has_many` en tu modelo `Remision`:

```
class Remision < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :atriremis
end
```

Con el código anterior puedes obtener los `Atriremi` que pertenecen a una `Remision` con el método `atriremis`; por ejemplo, para la `Remision` con `id = 1`:

```
Remision.find(1).atriremis
```

Ya con los registros identificados, solo debes realizar la suma, la cual puedes lograr (entre muchas formas) con el método `reduce`:

```
Remision.find(1).atriremis.reduce(0) { |suma, atriremi| suma += atriremi.valor_total }
```

Finalmente puedes crear un método en `Remsión` con este cálculo, lo cual deja tu código limpio y con el cálculo disponible para todas tus remisiones:

```
class Remision < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :atriremis

  def valor_total_atriremis
    atriremis.reduce(0) { |suma, atriremi| suma += atriremi.valor_total }
  end
end
```

Ahora simplemente debes llamar al método `valor_total_atriremis` en cualquier instancia de `Remision` para obtener el valor; por ejemplo:

```
Remision.find(1).valor_total_atriremis
```